# send invisible command from Electron to R via xterm.js

Tags: r, electron, xtermjs

I am trying to build an [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) app to open a terminal emulator (using [xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js)) and inside that to run [R](https://cran.r-project.org/).

Already found this very [useful example](https://github.com/Tyriar/node-pty/tree/master/examples/electron), and able to automatically run R. But since the Electron user interface will have menus and dialogs (including a data viewer), it is mandatory to:

- detect when new objects have been created in the R environment
- return (for instance a new data frame) to the Electron app in order to display it

I am thinking to have a set of background R functions to report all of that, however I don't know if:

- it is possible to send an invisible command to xterm (which will have an active R session)
- the Electron app can receive (invisible) messages from xterm (more specifically, from the R process that is opened within xterm)

All this communication between the Electron app and the R session within xterm should not be echoed in the terminal, of course. It should be somewhat similar to RStudio, where the new R objects are automatically reported from the console to the user interface.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.